# Transfer Data between List Widgets

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

Me and my friend are fairly new in c++ and Qt and we got a question. We already looked through the documentation and Google but we can't find a good answer.

We created a Music Player with Qt and everything is fine except that we don't know how to achieve the following with 2 ListWidgets :

- On the left side there should be a "GenreList Widget", with for example "HipHop" as an item and
- On the right side there is the playlist for that specific item.

So we want our player to be such that if you double click a specific item on the left side, it opens the playlist for the that item. If you click on a different item on the left side it should open a different playlist on the right item... and so on!

My Question is if that is possible with 2 ListWidgets?

Comment: Use 2 newlines to make a paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an slot for the [itemDoubleClicked](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#itemDoubleClicked) signal of the first list, and change the content of the second list widget accordingly.

You can learn about event handling, or in Qt terminology signals and slots here:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html